# How to hide a model charfield in a template?

Tags: django, django-models, textbox, django-templates, show-hide

can anyone tell me how to hide a model charfield in a template.
i tried many examples but those works on just regular input textbox. i am using crispy forms and i need to hide or show the text box on radio select here is my code

```
       var var_name = $("input[name='how_to_apply_check']:checked").val();
            if(var_name == 'Online')
            {
                $("#how_to_apply").hide();
            }
            else if(var_name == 'Others'){
                alert("Other");
                $("#how_to_apply").show();
            }
            else{
                alert("do nothing");
            }

                    }
                );
      });
</script>
```

"how_to_apply" is the name of my charfield.

```
<form method="post"  class="blueForms" id="id-jobpostform"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ post_type_value }}
 {% crispy form %}

 </form>
```

here i am rendering my form.help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `how_to_apply` is *name* of your text field, then your JS needs to be updated to,

```
...
if(var_name == 'Online')
{
   $("input[name=how_to_apply]").hide();
}
else if(var_name == 'Others'){
    alert("Other");
    $("input[name=how_to_apply]").show();
}
...
```

`$("#how_to_apply")` tries to find element with that id.

Comment: wow this works. but label of the field is still showing.how to hide the field along with the label??

Comment: You can find name/id of the label and hide that too. Or put both in a `div` and hide that, not sure how that is done in crispy forms though.